# Creating a Logon Screen

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

What is the best way to make password/logon screen? Iread somewhere that it is better to use a popup control. If so where exactly do I need to create it, in App.xaml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are number of things you need to consider while implementing a login screen for your Windows Phone 7 application. [Here is a sample](http://babaandthepigman.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!4F1B7368284539E5!220.entry) that can give you an idea of how to get started, if you haven't. One of the important aspects of a login screen is its appearance on the "back stack" - the list that grows while you are within your application, each item in this list is accessible through the "back" button. Ideally, you wouldn't want the user to press the back button and view the login screen. In other words, the login screen should never be in the "back stack". Therefore, it is probably best to implement the login screen as popup, see [Peter Torr's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx) discussing this.

[Peter Torr published an article on "Places"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx) which could help you design your application with the login screen.

Comment: Is the "[Peter Torr's post] discussing this" link meant to be to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding implementation of a popup, I posted a simple example in the Answer linked below which you can check out. In this case it implements a context menu.. you can populate the popup with whichever contents make sense for your login screen.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/e6d2a444-91d9-4d69-937e-689b24c36c09

I recommend reading the two links Indyfromoz has hooked you up with for how to handle a login screen wrt the navigation service. This are the most relevant and the current posts on the topic of handling login screens and the like wrt the navigation service.