# How to change screen's in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Problem with the UriMapper. The flaw is when i am navigating to my EULA page which navigates to first page which navigates to Main Page.xaml but, this navigates back to EULA.xaml, here i mapped the MainPage.xaml and toggled between EULA.xaml and MainPage.xaml. So, the problem is after EULA->firstpage->EULA but i want it like EULA->firstpage->MaiNPage. How to achive this? 
Regards, 
Panache

Comment: possible duplicate of [On application launch show 2 different pages based on a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263039/on-application-launch-show-2-different-pages-based-on-a-condition)

Comment: looks like the same question... there's also an open question on this same topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438088/how-to-change-screens-in-windows-phone-7/4438227#4438227

Answer (score 1):

You have a navigation loop.

Instead of mapping MainPage with UriMapper, map a virtual page eg. MainOrFirstPage.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a Navigation Loop ? I have this problem with a login screen : [Remove a page from Navigation Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440605/remove-a-page-from-navigation-stack)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a way to only show your EULA page once, have a look at these questions which all cover this issue:

[Creating a Logon Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596281/windows-phone-7-logon-screen)
[How do I clear navigation history in Silverlight/Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001462/how-do-i-clear-navigation-history-in-silverlight-windows-phone-7)
[How to change the startup page of a WP7 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441872/how-to-change-the-startup-page-of-a-wp7-application)
[Windows Phone 7 Sign in screen redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303403/windows-phone-7-sign-in-screen-redirect)
[On application launch show 2 different pages based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263039/on-application-launch-show-2-different-pages-based-on-a-condition)